# Error 400 Message - Don't know how to solve it for formula

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

Hi I've put together this VBA from looking through posts on this website which enables me to run a formula down a sheet for all the values. However everytime i run it i get an error 400 message. Where have i done it wrong furthermore how would i make this vba work for using a length determined by a column on another sheet.

```
Sub FillWorksheet1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("AF2").Formula = "=firstPart($G2)"
Range("AF2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AF2:AF" & lastRow)

Range("AG2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($AF2,'Naming Lookup'!$A$2:$G$10815,2,FALSE)"
Range("AG2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AG2:AG" & lastRow)

Range(AH2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($AF2,'Naming Lookup'!$A$2:$G$10815,3,FALSE)"
Range("AH2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AH2:AH" & lastRow)

Range(AI2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($AF2,'Naming Lookup'!$A$2:$G$10815,4,FALSE)"
Range("AI2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AI2:AI" & lastRow)

Range(AJ2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($AF2,'Naming Lookup'!$A$2:$G$10815,5,FALSE)"
Range("AJ2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AJ2:AJ" & lastRow)

Range(AK2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($AF2,'Naming Lookup'!$A$2:$G$10815,6,FALSE)"
Range("AK2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AK2:AK" & lastRow)

Range(AL2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($AF2,'Naming Lookup'!$A$2:$G$10815,7,FALSE)"
Range("AL2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AL2:AL" & lastRow)
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

The firstPart formula was created by a VBA to remove text following numbers to allow product codes to be gathered not just customer specific ones.

Comment: what's the actual value of `lastRow`? Also I don't know if it's just a typo but you're missing double quotes for `AH2`,`AI2`,`AJ2`,`AK2`,AL2`

Comment: It changes dependent on the values pulled from database, hence why i tried to make it line up to column B as this is the column pulled that is guaranteed to have data in.

Comment: All of the `Range(AH2).Formula = ...` should be `Range("AH2").Formula = ...`.

Comment: FWIW it would be much more efficient to use one MATCH formula for each row and then several INDEX formulas rather than using multiple VLOOKUPs which have to lookup the same value 6 times for each row.

Comment: Ok that's solved that problem. Now how can i make it run for the column length of B of a separate sheet?

Comment: Also thanks Rory i'll try setting it up with a match too. I'm completely new to VBA and well anything beyond simple excel as just graduated university and first job, kind of learning the ropes as i go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it something like this:

```
Sub FillWorksheet1()
    Dim lastRow               As Long
    Dim lCalc                 As XlCalculation

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        lCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    lastRow = Sheets("some other sheet").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("AF2").Formula = "=firstPart($G2)"
    Range("AG2").Formula = "=MATCH($AF2,'Naming Lookup'!$A$2:$A$10815,0)"
    Range("AH2:AM2").Formula = "=INDEX('Naming Lookup'!B$2:B$10815,$AG2)"
    Range("AF2:AM2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AF2:AM" & lastRow)
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    With Application
        .Calculation = lCalc
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Rory that's perfect exactly what i needed to use another sheet.

Comment: Rory, as far as I remember the `.ScreenUpdating` is automatically turned back ON when a macro stops running. Besides that ++

Comment: @Meehow Generally yes, unless you end the code manually. My rule is to **explicitly** turn stuff back on if you turned it off.

Comment: @Rory This might be a bit simple but what does the lCalc part do?

Comment: @Ben0708 It stores the current calculation setting so it can be reinstated at the end. It's better than assuming it should be automatic.

Comment: Ah thanks that's perfect. Also think the formula range at the last section should be AF2 not AG2, unless the AF is covered previously.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the quotes are missing.

You can also make the code more readable by just using one line for each formula.
For example:

```
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("AF2:AF" & LastRow) = "=firstPart($G2)"
Range("AG2:AG" & LastRow) = "=VLOOKUP($AF2,'Naming Lookup'!$A$2:$G$10815,2,FALSE)"
Range("AH2:AH" & LastRow) = "=VLOOKUP($AF2,'Naming Lookup'!$A$2:$G$10815,3,FALSE)"
Range("AI2:AI" & LastRow) = "=VLOOKUP($AF2,'Naming Lookup'!$A$2:$G$10815,4,FALSE)"
'ect
```

Comment: You should be putting those into the [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx). If the cell was formatted as text, it would show the formula  as a text string.